# How to solve Error on delete of './ss/#sql2-57b9-19.MYI' (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql

I had an error on my MySQL database while trying to index large mysql MYISAM tables. I get:

> Error on delete of './ss/#sql2-57b9-19.MYI' (Errcode: 2)

How can I solve it and is it related to my.cnf parameters file?
I'm using CentOS release 6.5.